# Grails Rest Request

Tags: rest, grails, request

I have this controller:

```
 def list = {

        withFormat {

            xml { render Customer.list() as XML }

            html {
                params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
                [customerInstanceList: Customer.list(params), customerInstanceTotal: Customer.count()]
            }
        }

    }
```

Which basically shows me all customers in my webpage, but it is also aimed to list as xml for a rest response. I'm using WizTools Rest Client 2.33 to call list method via rest. What is happening here is, if I call the controller via browser, everything works fine and all customers are listed as html in the page. If I call it via rest, the response I get is the same html page code rendered. In the code above, I tried to take out the html part, and that way the rest response is what I expect (xml). So, I think something might be missing, because the controller is not being able to recognise a rest request. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way withFormat works is by looking at, for lack of a better term, the action extension.  If you want xml to return instead of html, you're URL would need be something like:

http://localhost/app/customer/list.xml

Comment: ok. but i want the controller to handle both html and rest request. Two in the same controller. is that possible?

Comment: i changed the content-type of header to: 'text/xml' and it is now working fine.

Comment: Using the content-type header is indeed the key: see http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/single.html#6.8%20Content%20Negotiation. Maybe you can describe it in a proper answer?